# Disable KVM Kernel Module while its still in use

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, kvm, modprobe

In order to run a virtual machine, VirtualBox tells me to disable the KVM kernel module. I googled around and found out that KVM is included in the `qemu-*`-packages, but none of them is/was installed on my system (Debian Wheezy).

After that I simply tried to unload the module, but this doesn't want to work because it is in use:

```
# modprobe -r kvm_intel
FATAL: Module kvm_intel is in use.
# modprobe -r kvm
FATAL: Module kvm is in use.
```

I don't know what program is using it and I have really no idea what that could be. I also tried with the `-f` option but I get the same result.

My question is: How can I remove or disable the KVM Kernel module?

***Update:***

Here is the output of the `lsmod` command:

```
# lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             138825  3 
kvm                   404853  1 kvm_intel
```

Comment: Sometimes you can use `lsmod` to try and backtrack what is using the module.

Comment: @mchid I added the output of `lsmod` to the question. What programs should I terminate?

Comment: it says that kvm_intel is also in use, what is using kvm_intel?

Comment: @mchid Where can I know what is using `kvm_intel`?

Comment: I think I found it, try this command: `sudo service qemu-kvm stop` then check to see if it's still in use.

Comment: @mchid There is no such service, and I also wrote in the question that no `qemu-*` package is installed

Comment: you can `lsof | grep kvm` and then kill the PID running see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029526/how-to-find-the-list-of-processes-using-a-particular-kernel-module and you could also force rmmod http://stackoverflow.com/a/449211/3393576

Comment: @mchid Thanks, I found out that a program called `kvm-irqfd-clean` is running, but even `killall kvm-irqfd-clean` doesn't terminate that program

Comment: I found an answer on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/14645023/3393576

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644904/fatal-module-kvm-intel-is-in-use/14645023#14645023

Comment: @mchid Thanks for that link but that package is also not installed on my system ...

Comment: you can send SIGKILL: `sudo kill -9 {PID}` using the PID of kvm-irqfd-clean to kill it.

Comment: Check if the process has zero size; if so it's a kernel thread.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there some special reason you want to use VirtualBox instead of Qemu/KVM?

Answer (score 6):

As you noticed, there was an application using the module. The KVM module actually presents (part of) its functionality through  the`/dev/kvm` device file. So find out what application is using it  - e.g. with

```
$ lsof | grep /dev/kvm
```

Comment: This worked for me. Though the libvirtd service was stopped, qemu-system-x86_64 was still running, thus the module was still in use. lsof's output made it far more obvious. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you can use `lsmod` to try and backtrack what is using the module.

Here's an example:

```
kvm_intel             143597  0 
kvm                   459817  1 kvm_intel
```

On my machine it says that kvm is used by kvm_intel. Also, kvm is not in use. If this were the case you should be able to run:

```
sudo modprobe -r kvm_intel
```

and then,

```
sudo modprobe -r kvm
```

Comment: This does not work, `kvm_intel` is also in use

Comment: @msrd0 yes the output says kvm_intel is in use because it has a "3" instead of a "0". So, run `lsmod` alone without grep and look for what is using kvm_intel. You have to go back and start with the module that is using that is not in use. Go down the line from there one by one.

Comment: Why should I stop using grep? How do I benefit from that? Since grep only returns those two lines, it seems that there is no other module using kvm or kvm_intel

Comment: @msrd0 Actually, that won't help. nevermind